Runnable removeCallbacks doesn't seem to work so new Runnable does not start
I'm trying to build a simple screen tracker that also tracks your screen when your screen is off. For some reason it seems that the screenTimeRunnable doesn't want to stop, and therefore, the offScreenTimeRunnable never gets a chance to update the offScreenTime. I don't know if this is the issue for sure.
interface ScreenTimeUpdateListener {
    fun onScreenTimeUpdated(screenTime: Long, offScreenTime: Long)
}
class ScreenTimeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    var listener: ScreenTimeUpdateListener? = null

    private var screenOn = true
    private var screenTime = 0L
    private var offScreenTime = 0L
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private val updateInterval = 1000L

    private val screenTimeRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (screenOn) {
                screenTime += updateInterval
                listener?.onScreenTimeUpdated(screenTime, offScreenTime)
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, updateInterval)
        }
    }

    private val offScreenTimeRunnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            if (!screenOn) {
                offScreenTime += updateInterval
                listener?.onScreenTimeUpdated(screenTime, offScreenTime)
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, updateInterval)
        }
    }


    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        when (intent.action) {
            Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON -> {
                Log.d("ScreenTimeReceiver", "Screen ON detected")
                screenOn = true
                Log.d("ScreenTimeReceiver", "screenOn set to: $screenOn")
                resetHandler()
            }
            Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF -> {
                Log.d("ScreenTimeReceiver", "Screen OFF detected")
                screenOn = false
                Log.d("ScreenTimeReceiver", "screenOn set to: $screenOn")
                resetHandler()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun resetHandler() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(screenTimeRunnable)
        handler.removeCallbacks(offScreenTimeRunnable)

        if (screenOn) {
            Log.d("ScreenTimeReceiver", "Posting screenTimeRunnable")
            handler.post(screenTimeRunnable)
        } else {
            Log.d("ScreenTimeReceiver", "Posting offScreenTimeRunnable")
            handler.post(offScreenTimeRunnable)
        }
    }

    fun startTracking() {
        resetHandler()
    }

    fun stopTracking() {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
    }
}

The methods that catches these updates in a viewModel:
override fun onScreenTimeUpdated(screenTime: Long, offScreenTime: Long) {
        this.screenTime = screenTime
        this.offScreenTime = offScreenTime
        points = (this.offScreenTime / 1000).toInt()
        Log.d("RealityCheckViewModel", "Screen time: ${this.screenTime}, Off screen time: ${this.offScreenTime}, Points: $points")
    }

Logs:
2024-10-16 14:14:08.183  D  Posting screenTimeRunnable
2024-10-16 14:14:08.349  D  Screen time: 1000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:08.353  D  Posting screenTimeRunnable
2024-10-16 14:14:08.386  D  Screen time: 2000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:09.388  D  Screen time: 3000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:10.390  D  Screen time: 4000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:11.393  D  Screen time: 5000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:12.396  D  Screen time: 6000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:13.400  D  Screen time: 7000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:13.827  D  visibilityChanged oldVisibility=true newVisibility=false
2024-10-16 14:14:13.922  D  endAllActiveAnimators on 0x73c188c1b040 (UnprojectedRipple) with handle 0x73c058c54aa0
2024-10-16 14:14:14.293  D  Screen OFF detected
2024-10-16 14:14:14.293  D  screenOn set to: false
2024-10-16 14:14:14.293  D  Posting offScreenTimeRunnable
2024-10-16 14:14:14.409  D  Screen time: 8000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:15.412  D  Screen time: 9000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:16.414  D  Screen time: 10000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:17.416  D  Screen time: 11000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:18.417  D  Screen time: 12000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:19.419  D  Screen time: 13000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:20.238  D  Screen ON detected
2024-10-16 14:14:20.239  D  screenOn set to: true
2024-10-16 14:14:20.243  D  Posting screenTimeRunnable
2024-10-16 14:14:20.424  D  Screen time: 14000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:21.426  D  Screen time: 15000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:22.429  D  Screen time: 16000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:23.432  D  Screen time: 17000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0
2024-10-16 14:14:24.433  D  Screen time: 18000, Off screen time: 0, Points: 0

I've already tried using handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null), both alone and with what I already have.
I'm expecting the the screenTime to stop incrementing when the offScreenTime is off and the offScreenTime to start incrementing.
